# Regex - replace all the 11 digit numbers with link

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace all 11 digit numbers with links.

Right now the preg_match_all is not returning all the matches strings, but only returning the last matched one. preg_replace is just returning a single 11 digit number with link.

```
   //string with numbers to be replaced by links.    

    $test ="test these numbers 20150423011 20150423012 sdf sdfsdf sdfs fsdf sdfs dfsdfsd 20150423014 fsdf";

    $s = preg_match_all("/^((?:.*?)(20\d{9})(?:.*?))+$/",$test,$matches);

    foreach($matches[2] as $m){
    $replacements[] = "<a href=''>".$m."</a>";
    $patterns[] = "/^((?:.*?)(20\d{9})(?:.*?))+$/";

    }
    $final = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements,$test);
    echo $final; //right now gives out the last matched number as a link
```

Comment: you can skip the match and loop and do it with one preg_replace

Comment: So I ended up using  $re = "/(?<!\d)((?:20|21)\\d{9})(?!\d)/";  This doesnot select a 11 digit number that is part of another number, which I think is what I needed. Also I added a non capturing check for numbers starting with 20 or 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not fully sure if I understood your question, but I assume that you want to wrap your numbers starting with 20 using `<a href...`.

For this case, you can use this regex:

```
(20\d{9})
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/bB7mI3/1)**

You can use this code:

```
$re = "/(20\\d{9})/"; 
$str = "test these numbers 20150423011 20150423012 sdf sdfsdf sdfs fsdf sdfs dfsdfsd 20150423014 fsdf"; 
$subst = "<a href=''>$1</a>"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Your resulting string will be:

```
test these numbers <a href=''>20150423011</a> <a href=''>20150423012</a> sdf sdfsdf sdfs fsdf sdfs dfsdfsd <a href=''>20150423014</a> fsdf
```

Comment: thanks. this works.  But the link will be unique with id retrieved from database.  for ex: <a href='t.php?id=13456'> 20150423011</a>.

Comment: @user2411276 well, I based in your question that doesn't have that info, but you can add the logic for that. Btw, did my answer answered to you question?

Comment: do you think i should use preg_match_all and loop through the matches to replace the links with unique ids?  is there any other way?

Comment: @user2411276 certainly you can't do that with regex because regex are a matching tool. However, you can use preg_match_all as you said and then fill the links wih your ID. Or also you can iterate with preg_replace and replace the link

Comment: thanks.  preg_match_all returns two identical array with same numbers.  Is there any flag I could use to get one unique array.

Comment: @user2411276 I'm not sure, you could mark this question as solved and create a new one asking that